# SagePay v3 Upgrade .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, protocols, upgrade, opayo

I am just upgrading my .NET MVC to use SagePay Version 3.  How can I tell if my upgrade has worked to move to version 3, before the 31st July deadline?

The payment works and all goes through fine, but I can't tell whether I have done everything for V3 compatability short of waiting for it to fail on Saturday!

Is there any indicator on mySagePay Admin etc?

Comment: Sounds more like a vendor specific support inquiry.

Comment: It should be, but SagePay have moved their community forums to SO!  ;-)

Comment: Well, I hope they scope it to _programming/dev_ topics, not account nor "general" support...Otherwise, it will probably not be a good experience for their customers...

Answer (score 0):

You could make an API call (getTransactionDetail) or post up the Sage Pay TransactionID, and I'll check it for you...